# Передача string [] в функцию не используя переменную

Tags: c++, строки, функции

```
string Strings[100];
...
    case 1:
        Strings[0] = "1)Электронный каталог\n";
        Strings[1] = "2)Заказ услуги\n";
        Strings[2] = "3)Новости и объявления\n";
        Strings[3] = "4)О нас\n";
        Strings[4] = "5)Назад\n";
        switch (menu.Start(5, "\tМеню гостя\n", Strings ))
        {
        }
        break;
```

Есть ли способ передачи в функцию тех же строк без использования переменной `Strings, типа {"1)", "2)"}`?

Не обязательно использовать string [], можно и char*[]

Comment: В какую функцию? Для чего? Если просто для вывода - то вполне достаточно одного `const char*`...

Comment: @Harry Допустим, мне нужно будет с ними работать отдельно. Возможно ли всё таки как-то так передать?

Comment: Как объявлена функция? Какой у нее тип параметра? Вопрос совершенно бессмыслен без указания объявления функции.

Comment: Ну, например, можно передать в векторе (как `string`, так и `const char*`). Можно как одну строку `const char*` с разделителями `'\0'` между составными частями - просто надо будет сканировать эту строку в поисках подстрок. Вопрос, что выгоднее, понятнее etc - остается открытым.

Comment: @AnT Метод menu.Start() последним аргументом принимает String []. Не указывал, тк написал, что не обязательно хочу использовать string [], можно и по-другому

Comment: @Harry Спасибо большое

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не привели объявления функции.

Например, если параметр соответствующий функции объявлен как `[const] string *` или как `const string (&)[100]`, то передать в нее массив без объявления именованной переменной можно просто создав временный массив "на лету"

```
// Для параметра `[const] string *` 
using S = string[];
menu.Start(..., S{ "1", "2", "3" });
```

или

```
// Для параметра `const string (&)[100]` 
using S100 = string[100];
menu.Start(..., S100{ "1", "2", "3" });
```

Такой способ создания временного массива требует, чтобы имя типа было "однословным", про каковой причине мы вынуждены сначала создать псевдоним для типа массива.

(Баг в компиляторе GCC не даст вам воспользоваться первым способом)